# How to implement trim exceptional data like this?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a `List<Data>` that contains random objects: `i` and `o` characters.

The Data has two types, i and o (`Data.type`).

I want to write a function in Java that can arrange the list to  i, o, i, o, i, o ….

If it encounters several `i`, it should select the first.  If it encounters several `o`, it should select the last.

Can someone show me the simplest method to implement this?

Comment: You question is unclear: Show input and output, like a unit test.

Comment: Why don't you count the i and o's in the list and write the list afterwards?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag with `Homework`.

Comment: actually, it is not homework, I will use in my code, maybe my question is not clear enough...

Comment: Updated my question, please let me know if it's clear enough

Comment: No. Do you want to remove repeated leading `i`s to `i`, and repeated trailing `o`s to `o`? Like "iiioooooo" => "io", but "oooii" => "oooii" and "iiiooiioooo" => "iooiio"? Or what should be trimmed, and what not?

Comment: If there is no difference between multiple Objects of Type i and o, then it doesn't make sense to talk about the first of them or the last one. Don't they have to be consecutive? *ioioioio* would be trimmed to *io* (but not *oi*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there isn't really difference if you choose the first or last character to be desplayed in the result String, so try this [it always takes the first matching character]:

(*) assuming input is in the format indicated by 'str'

```
    String str = "ioooioooiooiiiiooo";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("i+|o+").matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        sb.append(str.charAt(matcher.start())).append(',');
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0) { 
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

use `sb.toString()` to get your resulting string from the `StringBuilder`

**EDIT:**

just noticed your input is a list, assuming it is `List<Character>`, you can do the following, of course you can change it to be `List<AnyOtherObject>`.

```
    List<Character> result = new LinkedList<Character>();
    Iterator<Character> iter = list.iterator();
    if (!iter.hasNext()) { /*handle empty list and return*/ }
    Character last = iter.next();
    if (last.charValue() == 'i') {
        result.add(last);
    }
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Character current = iter.next();
        if (last.charValue() == current.charValue()) { 
            last = current; //we don't care for i's which i is the last, but we do for o's, so we set it anyway.
            continue;
        } else if (current.charValue() == 'i') {
            result.add(last);
            result.add(current);
        }
        last = current;
    }
    if (last.charValue() == 'o') {
        result.add(last);
    }
```

Comment: actually, there is a difference, as those "i" character is different in our business logic, so do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Updated my question, please have a look

Comment: @MemoryLeak: I edited the second part of the answer [handling a list] to match your editted question.

Comment: good idea!!!, thanks!!! I used three loop to handle it, you idea seems really simple... thanks very much !

Comment: @MemoryLeak: editted again, forgot to insert last 'o' element. look now at the last 3 lines [after the `while` scope]

Comment: Just tested, but if there are several "o" the code above, can not trim  them .

Comment: @MemoryLeak: worked perfectly for me, can you give the sample input that it failed on?

Comment: You are right, excellent code, how can you find out this so quickly...

Comment: @MemoryLeak: possibly it was solved so quickly because it resembles an existing problem: Von Neumann unbiasing of a bitstream.

Answer (score 1):

If I see that right, you have defined some Data class like this:

```
public class Data {
    private char type;
    private Foo value;  // placeholder for whatever else this kind of
                        // object represents

    public char getType () {
        return type;
    }
    // other methods...
}
```

You also have some `List<Data>` containing a collection of these
objects.  Now you want to create a new `List<Data>` where all
sequences of more than one `Data` with the same `type` are conflated
to a single element.  If it is a sequence of `Data` with type `i`,
that single element should be the first element of that sequence,
otherwise it should be the last element of it.

That would lead to code like the following:

```
public List<Data> conflateList (List<Data> longList) {
    List<Data> resultList = new ArrayList<Data>();
    for (Data element: longList) {
        if  (element.getType() == 'i' &&
             (resultList.size() == 0 ||
              resultList.get(resultList.size() - 1).getType() == 'o')) {
            // only the first consecutive `i` is added
            resultList.add(lastElement);
        }
        if  (element.getType() == 'o') {
            if  (resultList.size() == 0 ||
                 resultList.get(resultList.size() - 1).getType() == 'i') {
                // all `o`s are at least temporarily added
                resultList.add(element);
            } else {
                // consecutive `o`s are replaced
                resultList.set(resultList.size() - 1, element);
            }
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```